# how to save an instance of a Django model to my database

Tags: python, mysql, django, model

I have a model called Job that I want to save to my database.  My template has passed its fields to my View function as POST data.  I am wondering how to from here take that, create some kind of Job instance, and save it to my database.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `my job = Job(); job.save()`

Comment: see [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said it:

> create some kind of Job instance, and save it to my database

```
job = Job(field1=value1, field2=value2)
job.save()
```

Also see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects).